# Obter coordenadas do cursor em C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor, posição-do-cursor

Estou a usar o `Control.MousePosition` para obter as coordenadas do rato, no windows 10.

Depois uso a seguinte função para obter um *PrintScreen*:

```
public static Bitmap PrintScreen(Point Source,Point Destination)
    {
        Rectangle R = new Rectangle(Source.X, Source.Y, Destination.X - Source.X, Destination.Y - Source.Y);
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(R.Width,R.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(R.Left,R.Top,0,0, printscreen.Size);
        graphics.Dispose();
        return printscreen;

    }
```

O meu problema é que a fonte está com `125%` e quando mando as coordenadas do *mouse position* para obter o *printscreen* ele vai para as coordenadas "reais", isto é sem o scale.

Como resolver o problema?

Comment: O meu ecra tem a resolução de 1920*1080. Mas quando coloco na extremidade direita o  Control.MousePosition Retorna 1535 em vez de 1920...

Comment: O Zoom sempre será fixo em 125%?

Comment: Nem sempre. Pode ser alterado. E nesse caso queria garantir que funcionaria à mesma. 
Se estivesse fixo era só multiplicar por 1.25

Comment: Apenas para esclarecer, o que quer dizer com **a fonte está com 125%**? O que você está considerando como essa "fonte"?

Comment: Acho que é aquele zoom do Windows, @Randrade. É isso mesmo, Leandro?

Comment: @jbueno Eu também imaginei isso, mas não havia ficado claro.

Comment: @Randrade  a tua interpretação está correta. A fonte está a 125%

Comment: @LeandroRodrigues A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

No Windows Forms pode usar [`Cursor.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Windows_Forms_Cursor_Position).

Fora dele provavelmente terá que acessar a API do Windows. Uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577528/221800) ensina fazer isso.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Point {
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public static implicit operator Point(Point point) {
        return new Point(point.X, point.T);
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

public static Point GetCursorPosition() {
    Point lpPoint;
    GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
    //bool success = User32.GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
    // if (!success)
    return lpPoint;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Cursor.cs).

Eu acho que poderia usar a [estrutura já existente no .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) para receber o ponto.

Comment: Também já experimentei. Mas tenho o mesmo problema, referido no comentário acima